# file of strings, find matching string in another file

Tags: arrays, file, directory

I have a file (File A.txt) and a directory that has File B.txt. File B is in a separate directory then File A.

I would like to read all the text files in the directory of File B and look File A to find the matching strings in File B and the text below it.

Here is a small snippet of the file
File A.txt:

```
**453454
```

File B.txt:(one file in a directory, want to search all the .txt file in that directory)

```
**84565
cat   dog       sd
fish  turtle    fg
```

expected output:

```
**84565
cat   dog       sd
fish  turtle    fg
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: Also, is it guaranteed that all the "header rows" in File B begin with two stars (asterisks) and none of the other lines do?

Comment: `re.search("\*\*%s\n(.*?)(?=\*\*)"%(84565,),open("file2.txt").read(),re.DOTALL).group(1)` ... i guess maybe

Comment: Yes, File B begins with two stars and none of the other lines do.

Comment: Hi, @Cindy. Can you share something about what you have tried so far so that we can give better advice?

Comment: hello @Roy Daulton. I have just added what I have tried so far and it gave me numbers not in that .txt file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `found` never gets set to `False`. The if clause you have would trigger only when an empty line is read. Instead, what you can do is to check every "number line" (lines with two asterisks and a number) and set `found` accordingly. I.e. if a "number line" matches one from "File A.txt", set `found` to `True` and if it doesn't set it to `False`. The last for loop would then look something like this:

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("**"):
        if line.strip() in foxnum:
            found = True
        else:
            found = False
    if found:
        results.write(line)
```

Comment: Hello BenignBeppe, but I dont just want the number that begins with the asterisk. I  want the text below it too until the next asterisk

Comment: @Cindy, I get the expected output with this code change. Don't you? Since the clause `if  found` is outside the other if clause, this will check all lines, not just the ones starting with asterisks.